# Unable to call getter for a Runnable in a ArrayList<thread>?

Tags: java, multithreading, methods, compiler-errors, runnable

I know I can use callables to get a return value but is it possible to solve this without using it?

I am trying to get the tempCounter value from the primeThread and add them all into the counter. But I received a "symbol not found" error.

Is it possible for me the call the runnable method from the arrayList in the PrimeCounter class?

```
public class PrimeCounter {

public static void countPrimes() {
    int counter = 0;
    int primeNumbers = 2_534_111;
    final int NUM_OF_THREAD = 4;
    int startRange = 2;
    int range = primeNumbers / NUM_OF_THREAD;
    int endRange = startRange + range;

    ArrayList<Thread> threadList = new ArrayList<Thread>();

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_THREAD; i++) {
        threadList.add(new Thread(new primeThread(startRange, endRange)));
        startRange += range;
        if (endRange + range < primeNumbers) {
            endRange += range;
        } else {
            endRange = primeNumbers;
        }
    }

    for (Thread t : threadList) {
        t.start();
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < threadList.size(); i++) {
        Thread tempThread = threadList.get(i);
        while (tempThread.isAlive()) {
            counter += tempThread.getCounter(); // symbol not found
        }
    }

    System.out.println("\nNumber of identified primes from 2 to " + primeNumbers + " is :" + counter);
}

// checks if n is a prime number. returns true if so, false otherwise
public static boolean isPrime(long n) {
    //check if n is a multiple of 2
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    //if not, then just check the odds
    for (long i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

primeThread Runnable

```
class primeThread implements Runnable {
private int startRange;
private int endRange;
private int threadCounter = 0;

public primeThread(int startRange, int endRange) {
    this.startRange = startRange;
    this.endRange = endRange;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    for (int i = startRange; i < endRange; i++) {
        if (Dumb.isPrime(i)) {
            threadCounter++;
        }
    }
}

public int getCounter() {
    return threadCounter;
}
```

Comment: Well, possible sure, but why would you want to?  There's thread safety issues that `Future` and `Callable` solve for you, if you don't use them then you have to implement the thread safe code yourself.

Comment: Can you tell how can I solve this issue? I know using future and callable will be best but I want to learn why couldn't I call my getter in this particular situation

Comment: Because you declare `tempThread` as a `Thread`, and `getCounter()` is a member of `primeThread`.

Comment: Also to be thread safe `threadCounter` need to be declared as `volatile`.  Your program will (usually) give correct answers but doesn't pass a sniff test.

Comment: wow can't believe i didn't see it. Thank you so much for going the extra mile to help me :)

Comment: No worries. It's a pretty obvious mistake, but we all occasionally make them. Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all read about [Java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) (your class names did't meet the convention)

With this fragment you say every thread to start, and before next tread to start main thread to wait the termination of this thread(Do you really want this?):

```
for (Thread t : threadList) {
    t.start();
    try {
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Interrupted");
    }
}
```

Finally you get a thread from arrayList and you try to run a method that this thread don't have.

```
for (int i = 0; i < threadList.size(); i++) {
    Thread tempThread = threadList.get(i);
    while (tempThread.isAlive()) {
        counter += tempThread.getCounter(); // symbol not found
    }
}
```

getCounter is method for primeThread class, but you have Thread class!

You can fix this problem if your class **primeThread extends Thread class**.